# IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings not able to save UserData.Contact object

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm making my first Windows Phone App

As per this tutorial [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680266(v=pandp.11).aspx ],
 "To save a serializable object to isolated storage using a dictionary, you just assign the object to IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings and specify a key."

In my app, I tried to save a **Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact** object in the dictionary.

```
appSettings["con"] = myContactObject
```

And then retrieve it later in another page using

```
savedContactObject = (Contact)appSettings["con"];
```

This code works in the emulator and the device as long as the app is open.But **when the app is closed, this dictionary pair gets erased.**
The dictionary is working perfectly for strings and custom objects. It only gets erased when a **Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact** object is saved and the app is closed.

Please tell me if you have any ideas to solve this problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact objects are not serializable, so application setting will silently ignore those objects. You have to write a custom logic to serialize those objects. Create a MyContact class, transfer all information you want to store there, and save these MyContact objects.

Comment: Hi Sinh,Thanks for the answer. I was able to get it to work using your idea. I converted the email addresses to strings, because if I include `public IEnumerable<ContactEmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }` in my custom class, it is not able to serialize. Is there a solution for this? And is there a way to know what is serializable and what isn't ?

Answer (score 2):

Call

```
Settings.Save()
```

To make it save those settings.

Comment: Hi Teemu, thanks for the comment. I am using the Save() function and the code is working fine for everything other than 'Contact' objects. Is there any specific way to save objects of that class ?